# Dotfuscasor Xamarin Dotfocused assembles are not the same one in decompiled apk

Tags: android, xamarin, apk, dotfuscator

I am using the ILSpy to confirm the Dotfuscated folder and work perfect, but after do it the archive and get the signed apk file, I de-compile the apk and use ILSpy and not Dotfuscater was applied.

I am using VS 2019, Xamarin forms.

Comment: I work for the Dotfuscator team. Are you using Dotfuscator Community (free with Visual Studio) or Dotfuscator Professional? What version?

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this issue; could you edit your question to include more detail?

Comment: My VS profile:Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019
Version 16.6.2
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.03752
Installed Version: Professional

Dotfuscator Community Edition   5.44.0.10087-6530a8d80a
PreEmptive Protection - Dotfuscator CE

Comment: I am moving the dotfuscated assemblies in post-build but and I have confirm the content in bin\release folder using ILSpy, but when I do the Archive and de-compile the apk and look into unzip app >unknow>assemble folder the content is not obfuscated.

Comment: It sounds like you're using Dotfuscator with a manual integration of some sort. Have you tried [the recommended integration method](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/getting_started_xamarin.html)?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved moving to Dotfuscator Pro evaluation

1. Removing my current configuration from csproj file.
2. Adding the follow configuration at the end of the file (go to </ project>
   tag and before the tag copy:)

   ```
     <Import Project="$([System.Environment]::GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.UserProfile))\.dotfuscator.user.props" Condition="Exists('$([System.Environment]::GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.UserProfile))\.dotfuscator.user.props')" />
     <!-- Set build properties for Dotfuscator. -->
     <PropertyGroup>
       <!-- Specify the location of the MSBuild targets, if not already provided. -->
       <DotfuscatorMSBuildDir Condition="'$(DotfuscatorMSBuildDir)' == ''">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild\PreEmptive\Dotfuscator\6</DotfuscatorMSBuildDir>
       <!-- Generate a default Dotfuscator config file (DotfuscatorConfig.xml) if it doesn't exist. -->
       <!-- TODO: Set this to false after the file is generated by the first local build. -->
       <DotfuscatorGenerateConfigFileIfMissing>true</DotfuscatorGenerateConfigFileIfMissing>
       <!-- Enable Dotfuscator for Release builds. -->
       <DotfuscatorEnabled Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">true</DotfuscatorEnabled>
       <!-- Only needed when using Tamper Checks for Android. -->
       <!-- TODO: If using Tamper Checks for Android, set this to the SHA-1 fingerprint of the certificate used to sign the app. -->
       <DotfuscatorAndroidSigningCertFingerprint></DotfuscatorAndroidSigningCertFingerprint>
     </PropertyGroup>
     <!-- Import the Dotfuscator MSBuild targets. Must be done last. -->
     <Import Project="$(DotfuscatorMSBuildDir)\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Common.targets" />
   ```

Thanks to the support team